# Amazon AWS resume instance import

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I was importing a VMDK image file into amazon ec2 using the command ec2-import-instance but the upload was interrupted by a power failure.

I want to resume the upload but I don't have the task id. Is there a way to resume the upload?

I can see the uploaded folder in my S3 bucket and the created manifest file, but no task id.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem too and research for a while for this. Sadly there is no ec2 commands to retrieve import task id if you lost it. But you can get the import task id using this trick: Go to the EC2 instance list and find the instance that is created during the import. Click Terminate, then you will see the import task id there. After that, Using this command to resume import task:

ec2-resume-import

you can get the reference at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-ResumeImport.html

Remember to specify --region parameter.

Comment: I tried looking at the instance list but there was no instance created yet.